# Getting all unique URL's using nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, open-uri

I've been working for a while to try to use the .uniq method to generate a unique list of URL's from a website (within the /informatics path).  No matter what I try I get a method error when trying to generate the list.  I'm sure it's a syntax issue, and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Once I get the list I'm going to need to store these to a database via ActiveRecord, but I need the unique list before I get start to wrap my head around that.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'active_record'

ARGV[0]="https://www.nku.edu/academics/informatics.html"

ARGV.each do |arg|
  open(arg) do |f|
    # Display connection data
    puts "#"*25 + "\nConnection: '#{arg}'\n" + "#"*25
    [:base_uri, :meta, :status, :charset, :content_encoding,
    :content_type, :last_modified].each do |method|
      puts "#{method.to_s}: #{f.send(method)}" if f.respond_to? method
    end

    # Display the href links
    base_url = /^(.*\.nku\.edu)\//.match(f.base_uri.to_s)[1]
    puts "base_url: #{base_url}"

    Nokogiri::HTML(f).css('a').each do |anchor|
      href = anchor['href']
      # Make Unique

      if href =~ /.*informatics/
        puts href
        #store stuff to active record
       end
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: I know the code works, but there's is a duplicate URL.  I need to make sure there aren't any duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the Nokogiri::HTML part to select only those href attributes that matches with `/*.informatics/` and then you can use uniq, as it's already an array:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'active_record'

ARGV[0] = 'https://www.nku.edu/academics/informatics.html'

ARGV.each do |arg|
  open(arg) do |f|
    puts "#{'#' * 25} \nConnection: '#{arg}'\n #{'#' * 25}"

    %i[base_uri meta status charset content_encoding, content_type last_modified].each do |method|
      puts "#{method.to_s}: #{f.send(method)}" if f.respond_to? method
    end

    puts "base_url: #{/^(.*\.nku\.edu)\//.match(f.base_uri.to_s)[1]}"

    anchors = Nokogiri::HTML(f).css('a').select { |anchor| anchor['href'] =~ /.*informatics/ }
    puts anchors.map { |anchor| anchor['href'] }.uniq
  end
end
```

See [output](https://gist.github.com/vnhnhm/f6f8079c7180b6b7ffeb52d23b563c3e).

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help.  I've written a bunch of stuff super close to this, but couldn't get it.  Really appreciate it.

Comment: As you were only iterating and printing the urls, you needed a way to check if they were already printed, hope this works well for you.